# Get query list parameter from Datatable in Django

Tags: django, datatable

I'm using `DataTable` with `django` and I'm trying to set up the `serverSide` option. Everything is working fine except the `order` parameter. Datatable is sending all the parameters to the backend in which the order comes like this:

```
order[0][column]: 0
order[0][dir]: asc
order[1][column]: 2
order[1][dir]: desc
```

I'm trying to get all the order parameters in a list with the [getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) function but I'm getting everytime an empty list

```
orders = request.GET.getlist('order[]')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I was sending the ajax as a form-encoded and it was getting the keys for order as a literal string `order[0][column]` `order[0][dir]`. What I had to do is send the ajax in datatable as a JSON and get the parameters with `json.loads()` in the view:

**DataTable**

```
"ajax": {
       "url": url,
       "contentType": "application/json",
       "type": "POST",
       "data": function (d) {
          return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
},
```

**View**

```
request_data = json.loads(request.body)
dt_draw = request_data.get('draw')
dt_start = request_data.get('start')
dt_length = request_data.get('length')
dt_search = request_data.get('search').get('value')
dt_order = request_data.get('order')
```

Answer (score 0):

Typicall you get an empty list for `getlist` if the keyword you are looking for does not exist. Try `request.GET.getlist('order')` instead.

Comment: I've tried that too and still getting an empty list []. But I can get parameters like this `request.GET.get('order[0][column]')`.

Comment: The problem is the user can select more than one column to order so I want to do it dynamic. That's why I want the whole list for `order` parameter :S

Comment: I found the solution. I've posted the answer, thanks for your help.